# Which time for buying online should be considered as muhurtha?

Tags: astrology

Pardon the apparent frivolousness

Which time for buying online should be considered as muhurtha ?

1. Placing the order date
2. Delivery date
3. Payment date (because it can be either COD or Credit/Debit time which differ)

Note: Please understand this question is asked with genuine concern and interest, as there are many people who follow astrology are also on e-commerce buying important things. This question is not an attempt to put down astrology instead is a question seeking answer for modern implications of astrology. It is observed from comments and downvotes that the spirit of the question is completely missed.

Comment: of-course, finding muhurtha is a hindu practice, which is centuries old. But there was no E-COMMERCE platform back then.
how's it even related?

Comment: Its related because nowadays many people are buying some important things like jewellery, clothes, footwear, home appliance which are not supposed to be bought on inauspicious days.

Comment: IMHO, that would mainly render it Opinion-based or too-broad. Also, please read on topic categories [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and see if you can edit the question.

Comment: @ChakrapaniNRao For small transactions date of use may be kept auspicious along with a small Pooja etc. but  for large sum purchase transactions alamnac muhurth could be consulted.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto Why not understand the question first before commenting/voting etc?

Comment: What is there to understand ? Didn't I make a clear statement ? BTW I am still neutral to this question, so neither upvoted nor downvoted. Also you'll never know whom who voted or not, so please dont make pre-assumptions. @Rickross

Comment: Your comment itself says that u haven't understood the heads and tails of the Q. I said comment/vote..so I obviously know that I can't presume that u hv voted here. @TheLittleNaruto

Comment: That's a safe way to presume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which time for buying online should be considered as muhurtha ?

One can put a muhurtha for placing the order date too.

For a muhurtha time for a purchase -

In case of credit purchase - 
The actual buy must be considered  at that time,  when one gets the possession of object/article from seller.

In case of spot cash payment - 
The actual buy must be considered at that time,  when one makes actual payment to seller.

Comment: thanks for the answer, just to be clear, you mean the main event is when we get the possession of the object we ordered, right?

Comment: Yes, In case of credit purchase, the muhurtha applies to that moment when one takes the possession of the object/article from the seller. In case of debit (direct cash) purchase, the muhurtha applies to that moment when one pays the cash to the seller. 
Obviously, muhurtha is the main event.
For placing the order, can put a separate muhurtha which is also important.

Comment: No I beg to differ I think we shd target that Muhurtha when the transaction is happening. Because the product technically belongs to us as soon as we have completed paying for it. In case of online purchases there's no guaranty regarding when we will receive a product. In case of COD too we can not fix the Muhurta because we are paying the money when we are receiving the product and that time can't be known beforehand. @ChakrapaniNRao

Answer (score 3):

Whether online or offline. The muhurtam is applicable mainly while placing the order (in case of debit or pre payment of goods).

If its a cash on delivery or something like that then delivery date should be considered.

But it is better to pay the money up front as there can be some unexpected delays in shipping or delivery.

And various muhurtas are to be considered for type of goods purchased. Many auspicious muhurtas are already listed in online panchanga websites like drik panchang.

Note: for those who are not able to find out any proper muhurtam or who.are not able to consult an astrologer, some days are ever auspicious and hence no muhurtam is to be considered for those days such as

**DeepAwali**

**VijayA dashami**

**Akshaya tritiyA** etc